# CSS class for menu drop-down background color?

Tags: css, joomla

http://volotechdev.com/nant/

I am using MaxiMenuCK on this Joomla site, and I cannot figure out which class to edit to change the background color (currently it's black) of the drop down (sub) menus.

If you hover over "Education" and look at the drop down menu you'll see what I mean.

Anyone see the correct class I can edit to change the background color from black to something else?

Thank You!!!

BIll

Comment: Also, in Chrome your menus are not entirely inside the background.

Comment: Did you see the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

The class is `floatCK`.

You could have found this yourself. Most browsers have a developer toolbar that is accessible by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. You can also get the Firebug extension that makes web debugging much easier.

You should have access to the HTML one way or the other. You could also have viewed the source of the page and tracked the element down. In Chrome you can right click an element and 'inspect' it. That's how I found the class you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Edit this `div#maximenuCK ul.maximenuCK li div.floatCK {background:white;}` or any color you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's on line 197 of maximenuH_CK.php.

Change the background color of `div#maximenuCK ul.maximenuCK li div.floatCK`

Comment: teach a man to fish - don't just give him a fish! ie don't just give the answer in isolation teach the original poster (and others who follow) how to answer similar (but different) questions themselves in future.

Answer (score -1):

```
div#maximenuCK ul.maximenuCK li div.floatCK{
background-color:yourcolor;}
```

That should work

Comment: teach a man to fish - don't just give him a fish! ie don't just give the answer in isolation teach the original poster (and others who follow) how to answer similar (but different) questions themselves in future.